# White AdView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, adview

I wanna know, why my Admob Banner isnt working??
it only shows a white Banner with nothing.
I used the test-Id´s.It dont show any errors.
Here are my codes. I hope you can help.:
Manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.chirag.slidingtabsusingviewpager">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
</application>
```

**activitymain.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.chirag.slidingtabsusingviewpager.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Julien Bam Soundboard"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>




    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pager">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.chirag.slidingtabsusingviewpager.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Tab1.OnFragmentInteractionListener,Tab2.OnFragmentInteractionListener,Tab3.OnFragmentInteractionListener {


    AdView madview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        madview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        madview.loadAd(adRequest);

        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Sounds"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Mc´s"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Songs in Reallife"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

I think, that the problem is that i used a LinearLayout instead of a Relative. But I have to use this Linear.

Ill be so happy if someone helps me

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

1. set 
       android:layout_height="200dp" for TabLayout (is better to set by percentage)
2. to move this lines from onCreate into the:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       if (madview!= null) {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
           madview.loadAd(adRequest);
       }
   }
   ```

b.t.w. this lines have no sense there:

```
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
```

Good luck )

Comment: I dont know how you meant it.. it dont work if i copy this code in my MAinactivity

Comment: Sorry, we should call super.onResume(); on the onResume(). Please notice the change on the code snipped above.

Comment: i dont know whats the problem but i addet these code and it doesnt shows any errors but if i test it it still show a white screen:

Comment: i dont know whats the problem but i addet these code and it doesnt shows any errors but if i test it it still show a white screen:                  **Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (madview!= null) {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            madview.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }
    Override
    public void onPause() {
       
        madview.pause();

        super.onPause();
    }

    Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        madview.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }**